# Adding portlet on one instance removed it from another

Tags: oracle, tomcat, amazon-ec2, portlet, liferay-6.2

This morning i encountered something really weird with liferay.

We have two instances that are running liferay(test and production) , both connect o a single backend oracle database.

We were surprisingly missing a portlet on the welcome screen on test and local machines yesterday but the production environment was fine.
This morning, we added the missing portlet to our welcome page. And immediately this caused the portlet to be removed from the production instance.
Any ideas as to what might have caused this?
Also, i cannot add the portlet on the production instance itself, because it can only be added once and therefore blurred out in the add applications window

One other issue we found recently,
We changed a permission on a page in local usually this propogates to test and production but recently it did not.
So i had to login to the production as admin and change the permissions on the page again.
Hoping this might give certain hints as to what might have caused this issue.

Since this is directly now affecting our production module, any inputs/help would be appreciated.

Comment: any ideas regarding this issue?

Comment: How do you sync the test and production environment - I mean especially caches and lucene index? I'd guess that this is a caching issue. And some more infos with the exact Liferay version and how you "propagate" the local permissions might help as well.